# Add missing fields with null values as per position mentioned in the config file in Python while parsing the JSON file data

Tags: python, json, linux, pandas, dataframe

I Have a config file

```sh
Position,ColumnName
1,TXS_ID
4,TXX_NAME
8,AGE
```

As per the above position i have 1 , 4, 8 --- we have only 3 columns are available. In between 1 & 4 we don't have 2,3 position where i want to fill them with Null Values .
As per the above config file i am trying to parse the data from  a Json file by using Python but i have a scenario where i need to define the columns on the base of position as mentioned above. When python script is running  if the "TXS_ID" is available it should pick the data from the JSON file & as i dont have 2& 3 fields i want to keep them as Null.

Sample output file

```sh
TSX_ID,,,TXX_NAME,,,,AGE
10000,,,AAAAAAAAA,,,,40
```

As per the config file i specify , data should be extracted from Json file and if the position is missing as per above example then it should be filling with nulls. Please help me if there is any possibility i can achieve.

Below is the sample Json File.

```sh
{
   "entities": [
        {
          "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
           "data": {
            "attributes": {
              "TSX_ID": {
                "values": [
                  {
                    "value": 10000
                  }
                ]
              },
              "TXX_NAME": {
                "values": [
                  {
                    "value": "AAAAAAAAA"
                  }
                ]
              },

               "AGE": {
                "values": [
                  {
                    "value": "40"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }      
          }
       }
    ]
}
```

Comment: @Benjamin Breton is there any suggestion or solution . please help me.

Comment: _Sample output file_ and _sample Json File_ don't fit together - the latter has no `AGE`.

Comment: @ this is for people who has marked negative votes. I need a reason why my question as marked with negative votes. If some one dont want to answer then its fine but why it was marked as negative. Can i know the reason

Comment: @Armali, please let me know if the question is not clear. I have mentioned above with source file , config file which i want to use it as input to my python script and then parse the data and create output file as above. I m not sure what else details are required

Comment: I didn't downvote the question, but in the comment above I pointed out an inconsistency in the sample data. Why don't you iron out this?

Comment: @Armali -- Downvote question is not for you. Its for others. I havent mentioned your name  . Sorry if you taken by mistake. My question is am i missing any inputs to give in the question..

Comment: … no problem, I didn't relate that comment to me; I just wanted to assure you that I considered your question not that bad. But why are you still ignoring my notes about the missing `AGE` in the _sample Json File_, and not amend that?

Comment: @Armali .. Added Age tag..

Comment: Shouldn't the _config file_ have `1,TSX_ID` rather than `1,TXS_ID`? If so, you should correct that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the *config file* line `1,TXS_ID` has a typo and is actually `1,TSX_ID`, this program works with your sample data (see explanations in comments):

```
import pandas
# read the "config file" into a Series of the "ColumnName"s:
config = pandas.read_csv('config', index_col='Position', squeeze=True)
maxdex = config.index[-1]   # get the maximum Position
# fill the Positions missing in the "config file" with empty "ColumnName"s:
config = config.reindex(range(1, maxdex+1), fill_value='')

import json
sample = json.load(open('sample.json'))
# create an empty DataFrame with the desired columns:
output = pandas.DataFrame(columns=config.values)
# now insert the nested JSON data values into the given columns:
for a in config.values:
    if a:   # only if not an empty column name, of course
        output[a] = [av['value'] for e in sample['entities']
                                 for av in e['data']['attributes'][a]['values']]

output.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```